# How to add a counter to a recursive function? [Python]

Tags: python, recursion, replace, count

The program has to replace two numbers within the list with a number that is also given in the parameters. I can't change the parameters, but I can create other functions also. In addition I must use recursion.  So far I figured out how to do the replacement with recursion, but I'm confused about the count.  Every time I try I cant seem to only replace the first two occurrences of 'x' with 'y', instead I always get to replace every 'x' with 'y'.
EDIT: And I can't use global variables.

```
def replaceFirstTwo(x,y,lst):
if lst == []:
    return []
else:
    if lst[0] == x:
        return [y] + replaceFirstTwo(x,y,lst[1:])
    else:
        return [lst[0]]+ replaceFirstTwo(x,y,lst[1:])
```

A correct outcome should look like this :

```
replaceFirstTwo(1,2,[5,1,2,3,1,1])
[5, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If x is only ever going to be positive then you can use, the negative version to signify that it is the second time that you are running the function. Before changing x to something to signify do nothing.

I have modified your function so it does this, however it will not work with negative values of x as the `abs(x)` will make it positive.

```
def replaceFirstTwo(x,y,lst):
    if lst == []:
        return []
    else:
        if x is not None:
            if lst[0] == abs(x):
                if x > -1:
                    x = -x
                else:
                    x = None
                return [y] + replaceFirstTwo(x,y,lst[1:])
            else:
                return [lst[0]]+ replaceFirstTwo(x,y,lst[1:])
        else:
            return [lst[0]]+ replaceFirstTwo(x,y,lst[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative using an inner function, which has no restrictions such as the accepted solution:

```
def replaceFirstTwo(x, y, lst):
    def sub(lst, res, count):
        if lst:
            e = lst[0]
            if e == x and count < 2:
                return sub(lst[1:], res+[y], count + 1)
            else:
                return sub(lst[1:], res+[e], count)
        else:
            return res
    return sub(lst, [], 0)
```